# Trigger introjs using onclick event javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple list I want to trigger intro js on click, here is what I have tried so far.

[docs](https://introjs.com/)

> Here is a [introjs demo](https://github.com/throne1986/introdemo) repo of what I have tried:

Here is HTML **update**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/intro.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/introjs@0.2.2/lib/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/introjs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>
<ul class="aside__list">
   <li<a class="main-side" href="/aside/main.html">Main</a></li>
   <li><a  class="services"href="/aside/services.html">Services</a></li>
   <li><a  class="Clients" href="/aside/client.html">Clients</a></li> 
</ul>

  <div class="main" id="main">
    <h2>Main html</h2>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>
```

Here is javascript

```
$(function () {
    var introguide = introJs();
    document.querySelector('ul.aside__list li').addEventListener('click', doStuff);

        function doStuff(){
            introguide.setOptions({
                steps: [{
                    element: '#main',
                    intro: 'Welcome to create movie page , Let me guide you through its features.',
                    position: 'right'

                },
                {
                    element: '.main',
                    intro: 'Please select theme you would like to use for your videos',
                    position: 'right'
                }
                ]
            });
        }

      introguide.start();
});
```

I have added an event to the first element of a list,

Unfortunately when I click nothing is happening but when I remove introjs function and put `alert('Trump is the greatest president ever')`  click event trigger the alert function and displays the message.

What is wrong with my introjs function?

Comment: how did you include introJs? where is your ```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../intro.js"></script>
```
what returns web console?

Comment: Hii Bern , introjs is working perfectly without click event ,

Comment: if you use jquery try something like: $( "ul.aside__list li" ).on( "click",  introguide.setOptions({
                steps: [{
                    element: '#main',
                    intro: 'Welcome to create movie page, Let me guide you through its features.',
                    position: 'right'

                },
                {
                    element: '.main',
                    intro: 'Please select theme you would like to use for your videos',
                    position: 'right'
                }
                ]
            });
        })

Comment: I have updated the question added the link to my repo can you check for reference : [repo](https://github.com/throne1986/introdemo)

Comment: can u put that as answer I am testing , I think its working , I would like to accept your answer, thank barny